# Fetching objects from database on Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm new on Laravel php framework. What I've done with this framework is to create routing, controller and a model, then I created some records on the database (not through Laravel, I did it directly to the database) but when I try to fetch them and show it on the view I can't see nothing and I don't know if I'm not getting the objects from the database or the problem is just I'm not showing.

This is my routing:

```
Route::get('questions/show', 'questions\ShowQuestionsController@show');
```

The controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\questions;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ShowQuestionsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show()
    {
        $questions = DB::table('questions')->get();
        return view('questions/showquestions', ['questions' => $questions]);
    }
}
```

The view:

```
showquestions!!!!!!!!!!!!111111!!!

@foreach ($questions as $question)
    <p>This is user {{ $question->statement }}</p>
@endforeach

foreach ($questions as $question) {
    echo $question->id;
}

echo $questions;
```

And the model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Question extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'questions';
}
```

On the log and console I'm not getting any error message

Edit:

The view v2:

```
showquestions!!!!!!!!!!!!111111!!!
<?php dd($questions); 
@foreach ($questions as $question)
    <p>This is user {{ $question->statement }}</p>
@endforeach

foreach ($questions as $question) {
    echo $question->id;
}

echo $questions;
```

This is what I get with dd($questions):

```
Collection {#165 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => {#171 ▼
      +"id": 1
      +"statement": "Pregunta 1"
      +"num": 1
      +"created_at": null
      +"updated_at": null
    }
    1 => {#173 ▼
      +"id": 2
      +"statement": "Pregunta 2"
      +"num": 2
      +"created_at": null
      +"updated_at": null
    }
    2 => {#174 ▶}
    3 => {#175 ▶}
    4 => {#176 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Comment: When I access to the view I just can see the show questions!!!!!!!!!!!!111111!!! message

Comment: Before your first `@foreach` chuck in a <?php var_dump($questions); ?>

Comment: Dump your results: `dd($questions)` and tell us what it prints right after the query in your controller

Comment: @Chris I tried but I get the same

Comment: @Thamilan I get the same as the beginning

Comment: @proktovief It shouldn't, when you add that, the controller either should dump the values of `$questions` or should print the blank screen

Comment: @Thamilan I posted how my view looks like now, I may did some mistake with your instructions, I still getting the same

Comment: It should be added in your controller _right after the query_ Like this: `$questions = DB::table('questions')->get(); dd($questions);`

Comment: why you are using `DB`? why not `eloquent` try this, in your desire controller call  `Question` model, `Use App\Question; ` and then replace your this line `$questions = DB::table('questions')->get();` with this `$questions = Question::get();` and then `dd($questions);` check your results.

Comment: It would be great if you post `$questions` value

Comment: @Thamilan I tried dd($questions) and works, I see on the view the fetched data, but the 'view' is not working, still like is not receiving data from the controller.

Comment: can `dd('$questions')` in your controller, and share the results ? I mean you getting the desire results or not

Comment: @Qazi yes I'm getting the results with dd($questions) on my controller, I'm going to post the values

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your view is located in `resources/views/questions` directory with name `showquestions.blade.php` and it should look like this:

```
showquestions!!!!!!!!!!!!111111!!!

@foreach ($questions as $question)
    <p>This is user {{ $question->statement }}</p>
@endforeach
```

also when you have model, you should rather not use Query Builder, but in controller you should use:

```
public function show()
{
    $questions = \App\Question::all();
    return view('questions/showquestions', ['questions' => $questions]);
}
```